# Suddenly Chrome doesn't render PDF correctly

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Everyday I print barcodes in a pdf from Chrome.
Today, suddenly Chrome doesn't render the barcodes correctly.
The pdf shows fine in pdf reader or Edge.

I uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled it but the problem stays.

See the screen-captured picture.
On the top line, the 2 barcodes should look the same but the 2nd one looks weird. This happens for random barcodes.

[image]

Please advise. Thanks.

Edit: I figured that this problem occurs only with Chrome version 57. Version 56 works fine.

Comment: This issue has been resolved in Chrome version 58.

Answer (score 2):

This could be an issue in either Skia (which produces PDFs) or PDFium (which draws PDFs), both of which are used by Chrome. It would be best to file a bug at https://crbug.com/new as I don't see a currently open bug about this issue. When you do, be sure to point out the website with the barcodes (or mention which program generates the pdf) as well as attach an example pdf. If you respond here with the issue number I'll try to direct it to the right people.

Answer (score 1):

i believe this has to do with chromes PDF viewer vs adobe's pdf application.  My best guess is adobe updated something and chrome hasn't quite caught up yet.  Usually this thing sorts itself out in time. I have the same issue at work occasionally with PDF's containing digital signatures, the signatures don't always print if the document is opened in browser.

Try this to fix it, hit the three dots in the top right, hit Settings > Show advanced settings > Privacy > Content settings.

at the bottom of the list there is a setting to `"Open PDF files in the PDF viewer application".`

Check the box off and see if that fixes it, it will either use adobe's plugin or use adobe reader to open documents.  You can always un-check it if this doesn't work or if you'd like to revert back.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. As I added in the question, the issue was with Chrome version 57. I downgraded Chrome to version 56 and it renders fine. Thus version 57 has a bug.

Comment: yea, I saw that after I hit submit. Either way, both solutions work. I just left my post up because it's what I do for my work PC's. Glad you got it working. @SamKong

Answer (score -1):

NEVER rule out, for e.g., Chrome Canary, that you are actually a behind the scenes [Chrome "Variation" field test Guinea pig](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1207022#c13)!!